# Using swift I cant work out how to go to a new screen once video has stoped

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avkit

I have an initial screen with a button on it which when you press it a video plays. Then once the film has ended I want the video to close and it to go to a different screen. At the moment I am able to make the button play the video and then when the video ends make the video close but it returns to the initial screen. Can some help? I have pasted my code below.

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

@IBAction func playButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    let movieURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "video", withExtension: "mp4")!
    let player = AVPlayer(url: movieURL as URL)

    playerViewController.player = player
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerDidFinishPlaying), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: playerViewController.player?.currentItem)

    self.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
        self.playerViewController.player!.play()
    }
}


@objc func playerDidFinishPlaying(note: NSNotification) {
        self.playerViewController.dismiss(animated: true)
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "finished"?

is it mean the video is ended or user close the viewcontroller or other?

for when the video finish, you need to use NotificationCenter

```
func playVideo(url: URL) {
  let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: AVURLAsset(url: someVideoUrl))
  NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerItemDidPlayToEndTime), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: playerItem)
  self.player.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)
  self.player.play()
}

func playerItemDidPlayToEndTime() {
  // load next video or something
}
```

for when user close AVPlayerViewController,

you can check [AVPlayerViewControllerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avplayerviewcontrollerdelegate) , it have several method that may fulfill your need

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes I mean when the video 'ends'. Thanks for the code I will take a look.

Comment: I couldn't get your example to work but have adjusted the code and added it above. I can now press a button wait for the video to the end and it goes back to the original screen I still can't work out how to go to another screen. I had a look at delegate but I couldn't work out how to integrate that into the code. any help much appreciated.